# How to create list of information and later search and sort that information?

Tags: ruby, database, list, sorting, search

I need to create simple book information list (database within code) which contain author, genre, name, release date and page number. And later search by author(sort by date, search by genre(sort by author). What is simplest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Book` class and then store those objects in an `Array`. It's pretty straight forward but you may want to read a little about Ruby and Object Oriented Programming.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :author
  attr_accessor :genre

  def initialize name, author, genre
    @name = name
    @author = author
    @genre = genre
  end

  def to_s
    "book name: " + @name + "\nauthor: " + @author + "\ngenre: " + @genre
  end
end

# create a few books
book_one = Book.new("Scary Book","Michael", "horror")
book_two = Book.new("Long Book", "Jim", "comedy")
book_three = Book.new("Short Book", "Pam", "romance")

# store them in an Array for sorting and searching
book_array = [book_one, book_two, book_three]

# sort the array by author
sorted_array = book_array.sort_by {|book| book.author}

# find the book(s) in the "romance" genre
romance_books = book_array.select {|book| book.genre == "romance"}
```

Comment: And how i would call for books from array(list all books and their information )  ? Because if i try" puts book_array" it gives me bunch of numbers like this :#<Book:0x27eb860>
#<Book:0x27eb800>
#<Book:0x27eb7a0>

Comment: It's giving you numbers because you're printing out the Object and its ID, rather the contents of its attributes (name, author, genre). You can easily change that behavior by overriding the default `to_s` functionality and formatting the string however you want. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help, you are life saver.

Comment: @DomantasNamikaze You're welcome. It is typically good etiquette to accept the answer if your question is resolved :)